# F# SRTP doesn't work for overloaded methods?

Tags: f#, overloading, srtp

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

My actual use case has nothing to do with `DateTime`. I want to call multiple overloaded methods defined on a builder `struct`.
They are call path dependent, return a modified `this` struct. So I can't pass the builder as two arguments with two independent generic types.

Have I overlooked something straightforward, or should I file a bug report?

```
open System


[<Struct>]
type MyDateTime =
  member x.Subtract(_: TimeSpan) = x
  member x.Subtract(_: DateTime) = TimeSpan(1L)


let inline f< ^DT when
        ^DT: (member Subtract: TimeSpan -> ^DT) and
        ^DT: (member Subtract: DateTime -> TimeSpan)
        >(dt: ^DT, ts: TimeSpan, dt1: DateTime) =
    let mutable dt = dt
    dt <- (^DT: (member Subtract: TimeSpan -> ^DT) dt, ts)
    (^DT: (member Subtract: DateTime -> TimeSpan) dt, dt1)
    
printfn "%A" <| f(MyDateTime(), TimeSpan(1L), DateTime(1L))
printfn "%A" <| f(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeSpan(1L), DateTime(1L))
```

(F# 7 SRTP improvements are not available on SharpLab, but that's not the point.)

Comment: posted https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1342